# Variables are empty in bash script after being assigned value

Tags: bash, shell

In my bash script, I'm trying to read through a text file, split each line up into three different strings, and then use them in a command.
Here's my script so far:

```sh
while read -r line
        do
                fName=$line | cut -d';' -f1
                fAddr=$line | cut -d';' -f2
                fPort=$line | cut -d';' -f3
                echo $line | cut -d';' -f1
                echo "--------"
                echo -e "Test connect for $fName"
                echo -e "IP: $addr"
                echo -e "PORT: $port"
                echo -e "NOPROXY"
                echo "Command: nc -zv $fAddr $fPort"
                nc -zv $fAddr $fPort
        done < "$fluxFile"
```

What I don't get is that when I do `$line | cut -d';' -f1` alone, it does show me the singular value read from my file? Am I missing something? The `fName`, `fAddr` and `fPort` variables aren't used anywhere else by the way. They exist only within my loop.

Comment: It should have been `fName=$(echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f1)` for all the lines involved

Comment: Add a shebang and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net